# How can i add each item to listview android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I got a list from console.log(js) using onConsoleMessage from webChromeClient

[image]

158 word

i did

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
                    list.add(a);
                    simpleList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

a is a string that have that list

i always got one item which is the last one `U.S. Virgin Islands` in the listview

How can i fix that, i'm really tired trying many things without success :/

Answer (score 1):

```
             ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
             ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String> 
            (getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
          
            list.addAll(Arrays.asList(a));
            simpleList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Where 'a' is a String type array.

Answer (score 0):

In one variable you should get number of data in adapter. Then in a simple while loop you will have data which are saved in shared preferences. You can toast it, see it in log or add it to an Arraylist.

```
int j = adapter.getCount();
int i = 0;
while (i < j) {
    Log.d("abc", adapter.getItem(i));
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Why wrong? Do you know what you want? with my code you will get all items that are saved in shared preferences

Comment: My answer is in Kotlin, you can use my idea and change my code to Java

Comment: Converting Java to Kotlin is easy considering Android Studio will do it automatically most of the time. The other way round for someone who doesn't know Kotlin is not always easy. If you feel that this code answers the question you should provide some description/explanation. Even for people who know Kotlin, it's better to have a description of what this does alongside the code itself.

Comment: You are correct @Nikos Hidalgo, I add description to my answer and convert code to Java. Thanks for your recommendation.

Comment: Hi @MohammadMoeinGolchin sorry for my previous comments, i was wrong,

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin i don't know how to use your code, for now, i don't have shared preferences, only variable `a` that returns many strings, i want to put each one in the listView insteaed of the last item

Comment: Hi @user11845248, your welcome, in my code you can see all the 158 words that you said you have. If you want to add items to an Arraylist, instead of line of log, you should write list.add(adapter.getItem(i)). list is name of your Arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for each` loop to get all the elements in a list:

e.g. `for(String list: a)` all the items are
stored in `arrayList`, then

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
             
                list.add(ss);
                simpleList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

'a' is a String type array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you please edit it to correspond to my code, i really don't know how to use it

Comment: i did ` ` `for(String aa: list){
                        list.add(aa);
                        simpleList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } `  just to be clear, a return a string every time, i want that string to be in the list view

Comment: ss in not defined and a is string, not applicable for foreach

Comment: set the adapter out side for loop